# How to strip of everything in []

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to strip of the leading text inside `[]` including the `[]` as below

```
title  = "[test][R] D123/Peace123456: panic:"
print title
title = title.strip('[.*]')
print title
```

OUTPUT:-

```
test][R] D123/Peace123456: panic:
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
[R] D123/Peace123456: panic:
```

Comment: `str.strip` doesn't accept a regular expression. You need to use something like `re.sub`.

Comment: (and N.B. that even if `str.strip` did accept a regular expression, `[.*]` would be the character class containing the literals `.` and `*`)

Comment: I was going to post an answer. Someone already beat me to it though. See the answer below @Jeremyapple.

Comment: When you say the leading text, do you mean the first occurrence of `[]`, or that you only want to remove the `[]` if it's the very first thing the text starts with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need non-greedy Regex to match first `[]` from start, and `re.sub` to do the replacements:

```
In [10]: title  = "[test][R] D123/Peace123456: panic:"

# `^\[[^]]*\]` matches `[` followed by any character
# except `]` zero or more times, followed by `]`
In [11]: re.sub(r'^\[[^]]*\]', '', title)
Out[11]: '[R] D123/Peace123456: panic:'

# `^\[.*?\]` matches `[`, followed by any number of
# characters non-greedily by `.*?`, followed by `]`
In [12]: re.sub(r'^\[.*?\]', '', title)
Out[12]: '[R] D123/Peace123456: panic:'
```